# Converting ASCII math notation to Python

Tags: python, sympy, mathjax, asciimath

I am accepting user input in ascii math notation and need to evaluate that input in python with help from the sympy library.

For example, a user might input:

```
2x^2
```

My understanding is that to evaluate this function in python, it would need to be in format:

```
2*x**2
```

My thought is that there must already be some libraries out there that could help with notation conversion but I have been unable to find any... Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parse_expr` function will help:

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (parse_expr, convert_xor, 
    standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication)
>>> parse_expr('2x^2',transformations=standard_transformations+
... (convert_xor,implicit_multiplication))
2*x**2
```